# popup dialog box background 100% height

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a onClick dialog popup window functionality. I have popup window of 200 x 200 px. onClick of the button the box is get opened & now I want that the content behind the box should be non click able which I have done but the problem is that it dosen't cove the whole page as it's disabled only the screen area & I want it should cover the whole page.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example/)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is contain everything else which you want to be unclickable in a div. Give body and the div `z-index:0;` and on click give the div `z-index:-1;`, this will make the div go below the body and everything inside the div will be unclickable.

CSS:

```
body{z-index:0;}
#MainDiv{z-index:0;}
```

Add this line to your function

```
document.getElementById("MainDiv").style.zIndex="-1";
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $('.box').click(function(){ //alert('hi'); $('.appear').css({'display':'block'}); $('.ui-widget-overlay').css({'display':'block', 'max-height':'100%','height':'auto', 'position':'absolute','float':'left','bottom':'0','border':'5px solid green','overflow':'hidden','scrolling':'no','margin':'0','padding':'0'}); $( ".ui-widget-overlay" ).css({ minWidth: $(window).width(),minHeight: $(window).height() }); }); });

Comment: <div class='appear' style='width:120px; height:120px; border:1px solid green; display:none; position:absolute; z-index: 1002; left:300px; top:300px; background-color:green; text-align:center; color:white;' ><a href='#'>Amol</a></div> <div class='box'>Click</div><div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div>

Comment: jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-minHeight - I want the crossed background like this link which covered whole content area.